# Import a JavaScript file with Webpack

Tags: webpack, handlebars.js

I got Webpack up and running and now I'd like to split my code into separate files.

Lets say I have this code in a separate file:

**handlebarHelpers.js**

```js
handlebars.registerHelper('timeFilter', function(context, block) {
  var f = block.hash.format || "MMM DD, YYYY HH:mm"; //default format
  return moment.unix(context).format(f);
});
```

Then I would like to include this into my main app.js file via webpack:

**webpack.conf.js**

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: [
      'handlebars',
      'handlebarHelpers.js'
      './js/app.js'
    ],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'www/theme/js/app.dev.js'
  },
  node: {
    fs: 'empty'
  }
};
```

This works, but how do I make it execute it in my app.js file? I found a gazillion webpack tutorials but nothing as basic as this.

I tried:

**app.js**

```js
import handlebars from 'handlebars';
import './handlebarHelpers';

// yadaya create handlebars
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

This does not work:

> ReferenceError: handlebars is not defined

But when I have the handlebars helper code inside app.js it works nicely.

What to do?

Comment: Have you tried this ? import handlebars from './handlebars'; where "./" is the path to your handlebar module.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your webpack config, you are referencing `handlesbarsHelpers` and `app.js` in different directories. But then in your `app.js` example, you are referencing `handlesbarsHelpers` as if it's in the same directory as `app.js`.

Try moving them into the same dir. Also you should only need `app.js` in your entry point if it's importing everything else you need:

**webpack.config.js**

```js
entry: {
  app: './js/app.js'
},
```

**app.js**

```js
import handlebars from 'handlebars';
import './handlebarHelpers';  // make sure this is in same dir as app.js

// yadaya create handlebars
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use [dividab/tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/dividab/tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin), its default `extension` does not include `.js`. And you need to do something like this:

```js
resolve: {
  plugins: [new TsconfigPathsPlugin({
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
  })],
  extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
},
```